# ScrollView too long therefore produce white borders

Tags: java, android, xml, scrollview, android-alertdialog

I'm still working on my android application and I still struggle with XML ans scroll views.
I want to display an AlertDialog which contains:

- A JPEG image a the top of the window
- two EditText under the picture, at the same Y coordinate.
  (and both the negative and positive button of the dialog which seem to work fine)
  the JPEG is coming from the camera and is quite big to display it in a dialog and hide the two EditText. I decided to embed this in a scrollView to allow the user to scroll if the picture gets too big for the display.

The probleme is that now I can display everything thanks to the scroll but I now have white horizontal bars which are useless and look really bad on some devices.

Here's the code to display the Dialog:

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View inflated = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_modify_picture, null);
    ImageView pictureIV = inflated.findViewById(R.id.picturePrint);
    pictureIV.setImageURI(FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            this,
            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
             new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/"+ p.getPath()+p.getIdentifier()+".jpeg")));

    TextView pTV = inflated.findViewById(R.id.pictureTV);
    pTV.setText(p.getIdentifier()+ ".jpeg");
    pTV.requestFocus();

    EditText yET = inflated.findViewById(R.id.yPictureET);
    yET.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(25, 65, 108, 174));
    yET.setText(((Float)p.getY()).toString());

    EditText xET = inflated.findViewById(R.id.xPictureET);
    xET.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(25, 65, 108, 174));
    xET.setText(((Float)p.getX()).toString());



    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setNegativeButton("Annuler", (DialogInterface dialog, int which) -> {});
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", (DialogInterface dialog, int which) -> {
        try {
            p.setX(Float.parseFloat(xET.getText().toString()));
        } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {}

        try {
            p.setY(Float.parseFloat(yET.getText().toString()));
        } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {}

        new PictureDAO(this).update(p);
    });
    builder.setView(inflated);
    builder.show();
```

And here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/picturePrint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/xPictureET"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pictureTV" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/yPictureET"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/xPictureET"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pictureTV" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pictureTV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/picturePrint" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Finally here's the white bar (there's another one under the picture)
[GoCheckTheWhiteBars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML826.png)
I'd like to remove the white bars so the image can be on the very top of the dialog

Thx for reading me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` from the ImageView and you will be fine

Comment: That's a mistake, but it still doesn't work without it

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned Jack, app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" is a mistake but after correcting it, nothing changed. (Idk why I can't edit my original post)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).